# adjust x-axis label scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I would like to make a ggplot graph with Period on the x-axis like 2010-01, 2010-02 ..., 2014-03

And my code are like followings:

```
 ggplot(Result, aes(x=factor(Period), y=No_Seats, colour=Airline, group=Airline)) + geom_line()
```

And the graph is like this:
[image]

As you can see we can see the period label clearly. I like to make the period a vertical label. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add

```
+ theme(axis.text.x =  element_text(angle=90))
```

Comment: Thanks @David I would like to ask one more question. What if i want Year is shown only? Thanks again.

Comment: try to put `x=factor(substr(Period, 1, 4))` into the `aes`, or transform in the data itself

Comment: NP, you can find everything on ggplot in Google. It is very well documented and has many visualisation examples. Try this site: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the scales library and provided x-axis is a date you can use something like

`scale_x_date(breaks=Dbreaks,labels=date_format("%Y"))`

Where `Dbreaks` is your specified breaks (most be date breaks otherwise it won't work) and format how you would want it to be printed. With the same library you can specify your breaks. For example

`Dbreaks <- seq(as.Date("2006-06-01"),as.Date("2013-06-1"),by='1 year')`.